# Use nested if condition in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I want is to write `df['good_day'] = 1` if

- `sunshine >= 8`
- `rain <= 3`
- `temperatur >= 15 and <= 25`

and otherwise `df['good_day'] = 0`

```py
d = {'sunshine': [8, 9, 6, 5],  
     'rain': [2, 4, 0, 8],      
     'temperatur': [22, 32, -12, 4],
     'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)

   sunshine  rain  temperatur  id
0         8     2          22   1
1         9     4          32   2
2         6     0         -12   3
3         5     8           4   4

df['good_day'] = 0

df.loc[df['sunshine'] >= 8, 'good_day'] = 1
df.loc[df['rain'] <= 3, 'good_day'] = 1
df['good_day'] = df.where(df['temperatur'].between(15, 25), 1)
                  
print(df)

   sunshine  rain  temperatur  id  good_day
0         8     2          22   1         8
1         9     4          32   2         1
2         6     0         -12   3         1
3         5     8           4   4         1
```

What I want

```py
   sunshine  rain  temperatur  id  good_day
0         8     2          22   1         1
1         9     4          32   2         0
2         6     0         -12   3         0
3         5     8           4   4         0
```

Comment: your conditions are not nested, just combined ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use this:

```
df.loc[(df['temperatur'] <= 25) & (df['temperatur'] >= 15) & (df['rain'] <= 3) & ( df['sunshine'] >= 8), 'good_day'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple comparisons and logical AND (`&`) operator to combine the conditions, finally convert the True/False boolean to 1/0:

```
mask = df['sunshine'].ge(8) & df['rain'].le(3) & df['temperatur'].between(15, 25)
df['good_day'] = mask.astype(int)
```

output:

```
   sunshine  rain  temperatur  id  good_day
0         8     2          22   1         1
1         9     4          32   2         0
2         6     0         -12   3         0
3         5     8           4   4         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use:

```
df['good_day'] = df.apply(lambda x:int(x['sunshine'] >= 8 and x['rain'] <=3 and x['temperatur'] >= 15 and x['temperatur'] <=25), axis=1)
```

Having said that, I myself prefer to use a solution as proposed above.

I checked the timings:

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit(lambda:(df['sunshine'].ge(8) & df['rain'].le(3) & df['temperatur'].ge(15) & df['temperatur'].le(25)).astype('int'), number=1_000)
# This returns 0.666049400002521
timeit(lambda:df.apply(lambda x:int(x['sunshine'] >= 8 and x['rain'] <=3 and x['temperatur'] >= 15 and x['temperatur'] <=25), axis=1), number=1_000)
# This returns 0.33816790000128094
```

Comment: The comparison is biased as there is a single 1 value in the example, the python version will perform less comparisons due to lazy evaluation, the vectorial way is faster when you have a more even proportion of 0/1's

Comment: @mozway thank for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use eval, I find it quite readable, using [queries](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-query) is also pretty handy.

```
expr = "sunshine == 8 & rain <= 3 & 15 <= temperatur <= 25"
mask = df.eval(expr)

df.loc[mask]      # Gets the rows with the relevant conditions
df.loc[~mask]     # Gets the rows which do not conform to the conditions
```

The output is then :

```
df.loc[mask]

   sunshine  rain  temperatur  id
0         8     2          22   1
```

and for the negation

```
df.loc[~mask]

   sunshine  rain  temperatur  id
1         9     4          32   2
2         6     0         -12   3
3         5     8           4   4
```